# Why don't default-template arguments work on using declarations?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to search for an alternative to the following dilemma. You know how when you have a template class/function with a default template-argument but you will have to apply the angle brackets even when they're empty? This is my attempt at making  a fix. I know I can use a simple `typedef` (`typedef X<> L`) but I don't want to use different names to refer to the class.

So I tried the following. But for some reason even when I supply a type for the template argument it still doesn't work. Why is that?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename = void> struct X {};

template <typename T = void>
using L = typename std::conditional<
              std::is_void<T>::value,
              X<>,
              X<T>
>::type;

int main()
{
    L l;
}
```

Errors:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:10:7: error: missing template arguments before ‘l’
>   prog.cpp:10:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘l’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is the same as for other type templates: you need to provide empty template brackets even for default templates:

```
L<> l;
```

The `using` declaration is actually redundant since the `conditional` inside it does nothing – you could just remove it, yielding `template <typename T = void> using L = X<T>;` – clearly not what you want.

And here’s the thing: there is no way around this; type templates are distinct from types (for good reasons, too!) and you cannot treat the latter as the former – you have to *instantiate* a template to get a type.

Comment: Funny how his code already used that fact... `X<>` appears in the `using` line.

Comment: But if it had been a typedef'd template, then L would have worked fine. Why is that?

Comment: @ZanLynx The distinction isn’t between `typedef` and `using`, it’s between template and type. You can also say `using L = X<>;` of course.